# can you show me some example for the Keymap.js,(The Definitive Guide)?

Tags: javascript, keymapping

```
function Keymap(bindings) {
    this.map = {};    // Define the key identifier->handler map
    if (bindings) {   // Copy initial bindings into it
        for(name in bindings) this.bind(name, bindings[name]);
    }
}

// Bind the specified key identifier to the specified handler function
Keymap.prototype.bind = function(key, func) {
    this.map[Keymap.normalize(key)] = func;
};

// Delete the binding for the specified key identifier
Keymap.prototype.unbind = function(key) {
    delete this.map[Keymap.normalize(key)];
};

// Install this Keymap on the specified HTML element
Keymap.prototype.install = function(element) {
    // This is the event-handler function
    var keymap = this;
    function handler(event) { return keymap.dispatch(event, element); }

    // Now install it
    if (element.addEventListener)
        element.addEventListener("keydown", handler, false);
    else if (element.attachEvent) 
        element.attachEvent("onkeydown", handler);
};

// This method dispatches key events based on the keymap bindings.
Keymap.prototype.dispatch = function(event, element) {
    // We start off with no modifiers and no key name
    var modifiers = ""
    var keyname = null;

    // Build the modifier string in canonical lowercase alphabetical order.
    if (event.altKey) modifiers += "alt_";      
    if (event.ctrlKey) modifiers += "ctrl_";
    if (event.metaKey) modifiers += "meta_";
    if (event.shiftKey) modifiers += "shift_";

    // The keyname is easy if the DOM Level 3 key property is implemented:
    if (event.key) keyname = event.key;
    // Use the keyIdentifier on Safari and Chrome for function key names
    else if (event.keyIdentifier && event.keyIdentifier.substring(0,2) !== "U+")
        keyname = event.keyIdentifier;
    // Otherwise, use the keyCode property and the code-to-name map below
    else keyname = Keymap.keyCodeToKeyName[event.keyCode];

    // If we couldn't figure out a key name, just return and ignore the event.
    if (!keyname) return;

    // The canonical key id is modifiers plus lowercase key name
    var keyid = modifiers + keyname.toLowerCase();

    // Now see if the key identifier is bound to anything
    var handler = this.map[keyid];

    if (handler) {  // If there is a handler for this key, handle it
        // Invoke the handler function
        var retval = handler.call(element, event, keyid);

        // If the handler returns false, cancel default and prevent bubbling
        if (retval === false) {
            if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();  // DOM model
            else event.cancelBubble = true;                      // IE model
            if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();    // DOM
            else event.returnValue = false;                      // IE
        }

        // Return whatever the handler returned
        return retval;
    }
};

// Utility function to convert a key identifier to canonical form.
// On non-Macintosh hardware, we could map "meta" to "ctrl" here, so that
// Meta-C would be "Command-C" on the Mac and "Ctrl-C" everywhere else.
Keymap.normalize = function(keyid) {
    keyid = keyid.toLowerCase();           // Everything lowercase
    var words = keyid.split(/\s+|[\-+_]/); // Split modifiers from name
    var keyname = words.pop();             // keyname is the last word
    keyname = Keymap.aliases[keyname] || keyname; // Is it an alias?
    words.sort();                          // Sort remaining modifiers
    words.push(keyname);                   // Add the normalized name back 
    return words.join("_");                // Concatenate them all
};

Keymap.aliases = {        // Map common key aliases to their "official" 
    "escape":"esc",       // key names used by DOM Level 3 and by 
    "delete":"del",       // the key code to key name map below.
    "return":"enter",     // Both keys and values must be lowercase here.
    "ctrl":"control",
    "space":"spacebar",
    "ins":"insert"
};

// The legacy keyCode property of the keydown event object is not standardized
// But the following values seem to work for most browsers and OSes.
Keymap.keyCodeToKeyName = {
    // Keys with words or arrows on them
    8:"Backspace", 9:"Tab", 13:"Enter", 16:"Shift", 17:"Control", 18:"Alt",
    19:"Pause", 20:"CapsLock", 27:"Esc", 32:"Spacebar", 33:"PageUp",  
    34:"PageDown", 35:"End", 36:"Home", 37:"Left", 38:"Up", 39:"Right",
    40:"Down", 45:"Insert", 46:"Del",

    // Number keys on main keyboard (not keypad)
    48:"0",49:"1",50:"2",51:"3",52:"4",53:"5",54:"6",55:"7",56:"8",57:"9",

    // Letter keys. Note that we don't distinguish upper and lower case
    65:"A", 66:"B", 67:"C", 68:"D", 69:"E", 70:"F", 71:"G", 72:"H", 73:"I",
    74:"J", 75:"K", 76:"L", 77:"M", 78:"N", 79:"O", 80:"P", 81:"Q", 82:"R",
    83:"S", 84:"T", 85:"U", 86:"V", 87:"W", 88:"X", 89:"Y", 90:"Z",

    // Keypad numbers and punctuation keys. (Opera does not support these.)
    96:"0",97:"1",98:"2",99:"3",100:"4",101:"5",102:"6",103:"7",104:"8",105:"9",
    106:"Multiply", 107:"Add", 109:"Subtract", 110:"Decimal", 111:"Divide",

    // Function keys
    112:"F1", 113:"F2", 114:"F3", 115:"F4", 116:"F5", 117:"F6",
    118:"F7", 119:"F8", 120:"F9", 121:"F10", 122:"F11", 123:"F12",
    124:"F13", 125:"F14", 126:"F15", 127:"F16", 128:"F17", 129:"F18",
    130:"F19", 131:"F20", 132:"F21", 133:"F22", 134:"F23", 135:"F24",

    // Punctuation keys that don't require holding down Shift
    // Hyphen is nonportable: FF returns same code as Subtract
    59:";", 61:"=", 186:";", 187:"=", // Firefox and Opera return 59,61 
    188:",", 190:".", 191:"/", 192:"`", 219:"[", 220:"\\", 221:"]", 222:"'"
};
```

JavaScript:The Definitive Guide:6th Keymap.js

Keymap.js: bind key events to handler functions.

This module defines a Keymap class. An instance of this class represents a
  mapping of key identifiers (defined below) to handler functions. A Keymap
  can be installed on an HTML element to handle keydown events. When such an
  event occurs, the Keymap uses its mapping to invoke the appropriate handler.

When you create a Keymap, you can pass a JavaScript object that represents 
  the initial set of bindings for the Keymap. The property names of this object
  are key identifers, and the property values are the handler functions.
  After a Keymap has been created, you can add new bindings by passing a key
  identifer and handler function to the bind() method. You can remove a
  binding by passing a key identifier to the unbind() method.

To make use of a Keymap, call its install() method, passing an HTML element,
  such as the document object. install() adds an onkeydown event handler to
  the specified object. When this handler is invoked, it determines the key
  identifier of the pressed key and invokes the handler function, if any,
  bound to that key identifier. A single Keymap may be installed on more than
  one HTML element.

Key Identifiers

A key identifier is a case-insensitive string representation of a key plus
  any modifier keys that are held down at the same time. The key name is
  usually the (unshifted) text on the key. Legal key names include "A", "7",
  "F2", "PageUp", "Left", "Backspace", and "Esc".

See the Keymap.keyCodeToKeyName object in this module for a list of names.
  These are a subset of the names defined by the DOM Level 3 standard and 
  this class will use the key property of the event object when implemented.

A key identifier may also include modifier key prefixes. These prefixes are
  Alt, Ctrl, Meta, and Shift. They are case-insensitive, and must be separated
  from the key name and from each other with spaces or with an underscore,
  hyphen, or +. For example: "SHIFT+A", "Alt_F2", "meta-v", and "ctrl alt left".
  On Macs, Meta is the Command key and Alt is the Option key. Some browsers
  map the Windows key to the Meta modifier.

Handler Functions

Handlers are invoked as methods of the document or document element on which
  the keymap is installed and are passed two arguments:
    1) the event object for the keydown event
    2) the key identifier of the key that was pressed
  The handler return value becomes the return value of the keydown handler.
  If a handler function returns false, the keymap will stop bubbling and
  cancel any default action associated with the keydown event.

...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Summary of the code:

- A new instance of `KeyMap` is created through the `new` keyword.
  Optionally, it's possible to pass an object containing the key map, to bind beforehand:

  ```
  {
    "key-combi1": func1,   //key-combi such as alt+a, ctrl+c, shift+s
    "key-combi2": func2,
    ....
    "key-combin": funcn    //<-- Last property should not end with a comma
  }
  ```
- After creating a new instance (`var keymap = new Keymap();`), the following methods can be used (listened in a logical chronological order):

  1. `bind` - Add additional key binds
     `keymap.bind( "key-combi", function );`
  2. `unbind` - Remove key bind
     `keymap.unbind( "key-combi" );`
  3. **`install`** - Attach key map to element (bound to the `keydown` event)
     `keymap.install( element );`

#### Examples

The easiest way to use this method is demonstrated below:

```
var keymap = new Keymap;                       // Create a new instance of Keymap
keymap.bind("ctrl_a", function(event, keyid) { // Bind key combi: ctrl+a
    alert("Key pressed down! KeyId: " + keyid)
});
keymap.install(document.body);                 // Attach keymap to <body>
```

An alternative way, with the same results:

```
var keymap = new Keymap({                      // Create a new instance of Keymap
    "ctrl_a": function(event, keyid) {         // Bind key combi: ctrl+a
        alert("Key pressed down! KeyId: " + keyid)
    }
});
keymap.install(document.body);                 // Attach keymap to <body>
```

Comment: >_> What is "not working"? Can you show your attempt in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?